# Why pass WSDL file to soap server?

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I learned a bit of WSDL [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language). I also knows what is [SOAP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/index.htm).

But [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Strong-soap.html#wsdl), when create a nodejs soap server, they pass the WSDL file to soap server. My question is why do they do it? What is the purpose? I thought WSDL is just a project spec (describing a web service set), why pass it to real server?

```
var soap = require('..').soap;
var WSDL = soap.WSDL;
var path = require('path');

// Pass in WSDL options if any

var options = {};
WSDL.open('./wsdls/stockquote.wsdl',options,
  function(err, wsdl) {
    // You should be able to get to any information of this WSDL from this object. Traverse
    // the WSDL tree to get  bindings, operations, services, portTypes, messages,
    // parts, and XSD elements/Attributes.

    var getQuoteOp = wsdl.definitions.bindings.StockQuoteSoap.operations.GetQuote;
    // print operation name
    console.log(getQuoteOp.$name);
    var service = wsdl.definitions.services['StockQuote'];
    //print service name
    console.log(service.$name);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WSDL document is not just a project specification. It is similiar to an interface in OOP world. It is a contract that tells consumer/users of your service the following bits of information:

1. Where this service lives.
2. What operations this service offer
3. What the messages this service use looks like i.e. the data structures.

Once you have coded this you publish this contract so that clients that use the service can use this contract to generate client code. That is the main reason we publish the WSDL.